# Is there a system call for random numbers?

Tags: linux, unix, random

As everyone knows, if you want a truly random number (perhaps to pass to `srand()`), you open `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` and read a few bytes.  But is there a lighter-weight way to do it, perhaps a system call?

[P.S. Yes, I know, opening and reading `/dev/random` isn't going to take very long, either.  But I'm just wondering if there are other options.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getrandom](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) seems to fit the bill, unless that is what you meant by reading from /dev/random or /dev/urandom, since that is exactly what it does. It is a specific system call.

Comment: No, that's exactly what I meant!  Thanks.

Comment: The `getrandom()` system call was introduced in version 3.17 of the Linux kernel, released 2014-10-05. For example the Linux Mint 17.3 system I'm typing this on doesn't have it (it uses 3.16).